# Magento 2: complications after upgrad

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I  have upgrade magento from 2.1.11 to latest version 2.2.3

After complete upgrade some issues with website display:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please update your modules: Run "composer install" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_Customer db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.12, currently installed - 2.0.9
Mageplaza_Smtp db schema version: defined in codebase - 1.1.0, currently installed - 1.2.0
Mageplaza_Smtp db data version: defined in codebase - 1.1.0, currently installed - 1.2.0
```

When I try run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Then get error: "sorry something went wrong...."
[image]

Log exception file:

```
[2018-04-08 09:19:51] main.CRITICAL: Asymmetric transaction rollback. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Asymmetric transaction rollback. at /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:316)"} []
[2018-04-08 09:20:03] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: DELETE FROM catalog_category_product_index_replica {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\DeadlockException(code: 1213): SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: DELETE FROM catalog_category_product_index_replica at /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:555, Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 40001): SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: DELETE FROM catalog_category_product_index_replica at /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 40001): SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction at /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []
[2018-04-08 09:31:03] main.CRITICAL: Dotmailer connector API endpoint cannot be empty. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): Dotmailer connector API endpoint cannot be empty. at /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Model/Apiconnector/Client.php:118)"} []
[2018-04-08 09:32:15] main.CRITICAL: Asymmetric transaction rollback. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Asymmetric transaction rollback. at /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:316)"} []
[2018-04-08 09:43:04] main.CRITICAL: Asymmetric transaction rollback. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Asymmetric transaction rollback. at /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:316)"} []
```

Comment: What happens when you run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` ?

Comment: unfortunately No result :(

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, can't fix for couple of days now...

Comment: I have opened ticket on github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14624  You can join to issue.